# How can I join path fragments using objective-C in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, path, filesystems

What's the objective-C equivalent of python's `os.path.join` in iOS? e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("foo", "bar", "buuxometer", "hi.jpg")
'foo/bar/buuxometer/hi.jpg'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for [[NSString pathWithComponents]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/pathWithComponents%3a) which, per the link will:

> Returns a string built from the strings in a given array by concatenating them with a path separator between each pair.

In your sample:

```
NSArray *components = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", @"buuxometer", @"hi.jpg", nil];
NSString *path = [NSString pathWithComponents:components];
```

Comment: quite right, jolly good! note you can also do `@[@"foo", @"bar", @"buuxometer", @"hi.jpg"]`